# Troubles with mercurial 1.9 and ssh

Tags: linux, mercurial

Last weekend (16. July 2011) our mercurial packages auto-updated to the newest 1.9 mercurial binaries using the mercurial-stable ppa on a ubuntu lucid.

Now pulling from repository over SSH no longer works.
Following error is displayed:

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/usr/share/mercurial-server/hg-ssh", line 86, in <module>
remote:     dispatch.dispatch(['-R', repo, 'serve', '--stdio'])
remote:   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 31, in dispatch
remote:     if req.ferr:
remote: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ferr'
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

In the mercurial 1.9 [upgrade notes](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UpgradeNotes#A1.9:_minor_changes.2C_drop_experimental_parentdelta_format) there is an 'interesting' note:

```
contrib/hg-ssh from older Mercurial releases will not be compatible with version 1.9, please update your copy.
```

Has somebody an idea how to upgrade (if there is already a version) the package mercurial-server?
Or do we need to upgrade something else? (New python scripts?)

If there is no new version yet of the necessary packages, how to downgrade to the previous 1.7.5 (ubuntu lucid)?

Any help is really appreciated as our development processes are really slowed down by this fact. :S

Thanks

Comment: Well if somebody gives a negative vote, it may also be interesting to knowing why!?!? Mercurial is related to development!!!

Comment: +1 even if the question should have been posted on mercurial mailing list, I think it's helpful enough here (or on superuser.com).

Comment: @Danilo: it's possible that it has been downvoted due to the exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730529/troubles-with-mercurial-1-9-and-ssh - what's going on? Why is the same question posted twice? Do you have two active accounts? You should kill one off.

Comment: Wait, I think that was someone else messing up their entirely unrelated question somehow. Rolled back their changes...

Comment: @Chris: Urghs... that's really odd, I posted my question only once... but I see that in the question you linked, my text is displayed... (sound like a stackoverflow bug?)

Comment: @Danilo: I think it's a problem user. Not sure quite what the user is doing. I've rolled back his changes, he rolled back my rollback, after flagging it and waiting some time (and asking what the user was doing) I've just rolled it back again. I'll keep track of that question... hope it doesn't cause trouble with this question for you.

Comment: I agree that this question should stay on SO rather than be migrated to SU. SU has less than 3% of the number of mercurial-tagged questions, the problem and solution are directly related to Mercurial, and the solution is to edit one of Mercurial's scripts. *I can see a migration if both the actual problem and solution belonged somewhere else and Mercurial simply exposed the symptoms of the problem.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, found a (workaround) solution by editing a python script.

Edit the script /usr/share/mercurial-server/hg-ssh
At the end of the script replace the line:

```
dispatch.dispatch(['-R', repo, 'serve', '--stdio'])
```

with the line:

```
dispatch.dispatch(dispatch.request(['-R', repo, 'serve', '--stdio']))
```

Replace also:

```
dispatch.dispatch(['init', repo])
```

with the line:

```
dispatch.dispatch(dispatch.request(['init', repo]))
```

This works for us.

Hopefully this saves to somebody else burning 4 hours of work with googleing and learning basics of python. :S

Comment: Yep, [`dispatch` API changed](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ApiChanges#Changes_after_1.8).

Comment: @Danilo Tommasina: If it means anything to you, I've just run into that exact same issue, and your question, along with your generously posted answer has saved me a lot of time and headache. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As to API change, if yoy take a look at the [commit's comment](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg/rev/08bfec2ef031), "[request class] currently only stores the arguments", it looks a bit irresponsible, don't you think? Cosmetic change that breaks API...

Comment: Okay this did save me :-). I'd posted a question on the Gentoo User mailing list thinking this was a gentoo specific issue, but someone pointed me here. Thanks :-)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot! 15 minutes, instead of a few hours!

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of mercurial-server are updated to support the API changes, but **may require** the `refresh-auth` script to be rerun for installations being upgraded.